# Predicted probability at the mean decreases when more variables are added to a Logistic regression model

Tags: logistic, prediction, stata, marginal-effect

I have been thinking about this question for the past couple days and have not been able to come to a conclusion.
I am running a logistic regression and want to calculate the % change in predicted probability from adding a variable of interest. I am using STATA for this is and here is my code.

First, I run a regression with the full specification and calculate the predicted probability for the average individual:

```
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/margex
quietly logit outcome i.sex age distance i.group
margins, atmeans
```

I get the following:

```
             |            Delta-method
             |     Margin   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       _cons |   .0586319    .018623     3.15   0.002     .0221315    .0951323
```

If I calculate the predicted probability excluding without distance for the average individual,

```
quietly logit outcome i.sex age i.group
margins, atmeans

        |            Delta-method
             |     Margin   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       _cons |   .0962654   .0072607    13.26   0.000     .0820347     .110496
```

I find this quite strange in that the predicted probability at the mean decreases when you add another variable. Even though this is an example, I found the same to be true in my research. I am baffled at why this is so and do not think this is overfitting because I am using the same dataset in all cases.

Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First, you are making a prediction for a Frankenstein of hypothetical case when calculating for the average person. For example, your average person in this dataset in half female and half male! This does not make much sense.

If you set the categorical variables to their base values, this would work somewhat better (especially coupled with carefully chosen base levels):

```
margins, at((mean) _continuous (base) _factor)
```

Personally, I would just calculate the average of the predictions (rather than a prediction for the average person) with:

```
margins
```

This will give you the same prediction from both models: .1696667.

**The difference you see with your code is both because you have a different average person and a different model when you take distance into account.** You can get much closer predictions if you evaluate at own value of distance, keeping other variables at their means. This is much more of an apples-to-apples comparison (though a slight difference remains since by including distance you are changing the variance and the coefficients are scaled by the standard deviation of the error):

```
. use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/margex, clear
(Artificial data for margins)

. qui logit outcome i.sex age i.group distance

. margins, at((mean) sex age group (asobserved) distance) 

Predictive margins                              Number of obs     =      3,000
Model VCE    : OIM

Expression   : Pr(outcome), predict()
at           : 0.sex           =    .4993333 (mean)
               1.sex           =    .5006667 (mean)
               age             =      39.799 (mean)
               1.group         =    .3996667 (mean)
               2.group         =    .3726667 (mean)
               3.group         =    .2276667 (mean)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |     Margin   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       _cons |   .0961625   .0072624    13.24   0.000     .0819284    .1103966
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. qui logit outcome i.sex age i.group

. margins, atmeans

Adjusted predictions                            Number of obs     =      3,000
Model VCE    : OIM

Expression   : Pr(outcome), predict()
at           : 0.sex           =    .4993333 (mean)
               1.sex           =    .5006667 (mean)
               age             =      39.799 (mean)
               1.group         =    .3996667 (mean)
               2.group         =    .3726667 (mean)
               3.group         =    .2276667 (mean)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |     Margin   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       _cons |   .0962654   .0072607    13.26   0.000     .0820347     .110496
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```